# Twisted server: monkey-patch file

Tags: python, twisted, monkeypatching

I'm running Twisted (Python 2.7.x) on Alpine Linux 3.7 inside Docker.

I now wanted to use the `twisted.internet.inotify` module, but it fails loading.

It's triggering the following exception in [`twisted.python._inotify`](https://github.com/racker/python-twisted-core/blob/a887b40fc1fa186507f90824999f7b4db2623597/twisted/python/_inotify.py#L99):

```
name = ctypes.util.find_library('c')
if not name:
    raise ImportError("Can't find C library.")
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
initializeModule(libc)
```

The problem is that Alpine Linux 3.x has a bug which makes `ctypes.util.find_library('c')` return `None`.

I've compared the code with the [`inotify` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify), which I've successfully used in Alpine before, and that one deals with the issue in [the following way](https://github.com/dsoprea/PyInotify/blob/78670d829ba363dcdde814513990e31e0e8eb7b7/inotify/library.py#L6):

```
_FILEPATH = ctypes.util.find_library('c')
if _FILEPATH is None:
    _FILEPATH = 'libc.so.6'

instance = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(_FILEPATH)
```

So i've tried calling `ctypes.util.find_library('libc.so.6')` in the interpreter, and that call succeeds.

What I now want to do is to monkey-patch `twisted.python._inotify` so that it loads `libc.so.6` instead of `c`, but I'm unaware of how I can do that, because I can't load the module at all.

I have one option, which is to `sed` the source code during `docker build`, or possibly even inside the server right after it starts, but that feels like a hack.

I've seen that Twisted contains a MonkeyPatch module, but I have no idea on how to use it, or if it is even suited for this task.

How can I solve this problem in the cleanest possible way?

---

Note: The server is running as non-root, so it has no write access to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/_inotify.py`.

This means that I either have to `sed` it in the Dockerfile, or patch in in-memory when the server starts, before it loads the module (if that's possible, I'd prefer that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to anything else, I hope that you contribute a patch to Twisted to either solve this problem outright or make it easier to solve from application code or at an operations level.

That said, here's a monkey-patch that should do for you:

```
import ctypes.util
def fixed_find_library(name):
    if name == "c":
        result = original_find_library(name)
        if result is not None:
            return result
        else:
            return "libc.so.6"
    return original_find_library(name)
original_find_library = ctypes.util.find_library
ctypes.util.find_library = fixed_find_library

# The rest of your application code...
```

This works simply by codifying the logic from your question which you suggest works around the problem.  As long as this code runs before `_inotify.py` is imported then when it does get imported it will end up using the "fixed" version instead of the original.

Comment: I'm not sure if patching Twisted's source code is the correct approach. This is a problem of Alpine Linux.

Comment: If you _want_ to carry a patch against Twisted to make your software work, I guess that's your call...

Answer (score 0):

While monkey-patching as Jean-Paul indicates seems to be the best fix, here is an approach which modifies Twisted's source code.

When using the Python Docker API to run the container:

```
container = client.containers.run(...)
patch = 'sed -i.bak s/raise\ ImportError/name\ =\ \\"libc.so.6\\"\ #\ raise\ ImportError/g /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/_inotify.py'
print container.exec_run(patch, user='root')
```

or when in bash inside the container:

```
sed -i.bak s/raise\ ImportError/name\ =\ \"libc.so.6\"\ #\ raise\ ImportError/g /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/_inotify.py
```